# clojure: best approach for singleton-like data connection

Tags: clojure

I'm creating a connection to elasticsearch (but substitute any other data source of your liking here), and it will be based on environment or config file parameters at runtime.  It looks like this:

```
(defn create-conn
  "Connect to the given uri. This is a persistent conn managed by clj-http (apache)."
  ([uri]
   ( ;;; create a persistent connection using clj-http / elastic
   ...)
  ([]
   (create-conn (or (System/getenv "ES_URL")
                    (cfg/get-url-from-config-file)
                    "http://localhost:9200"))))
```

Because the connection will not change during the lifetime of the server, I will only need to run this function once and cache the result.  There are a few ways to do this:

1 - `memoize` it -- while this works, it doesn't feel like the right approach since I'd only be caching one thing

2 - use a state manager like Component or mount; since I'm not really managing state, just setting and forgetting, and only using it for this one thing, it feels a little overkill.  For example, how is the following superior to #3 below?

```
; mount version -- good, but how is this better than #3 below?
(defstate conn :start (getconn))
(mount/start #'elastic/conn)   ;; somewhere else, must start mount
```

3 - `def` it.  Even though running `create-conn` does not actually perform any network activity, I'd rather not run it when the file loads, which is what would happen if I just did a regular `def` on it, so I'd have to do something like the following... note that the `getconn` function is for convenience, so that I don't have to `deref` `conn` directly:

```
(def conn (delay (create-conn)))
(defn getconn [] @conn)
```

4 - use an `atom` -- straightforward, but this is not a var which needs to change, and it introduces state where it is not really necessary:

```
(def conn (atom nil))
(def getconn []
  (if-not @conn (reset! conn (create-conn)))
  @conn)
```

5 - `[insert your idea here]`

Of the above, I prefer 3, since it is using immutable data, even though the `delay` is a little clunky.  What is your preference, whether it's from the above list, or your own solution?

Comment: Dynamic vars certainly used to be the idiomatic thing for this kind of use case, though I don't know if best-practice has moved on.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I got a sense that the community has moved away from dynamic vars. For example, last I heard `clojure/java.jdbc` has eliminated them.

Comment: May I know which approach you ended up with and why?

Comment: I think another way to do it might be using memoize? https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/memoize

Answer (score 2):

[Mount](https://github.com/tolitius/mount) or [component](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component) are built exactly for this -  controlling state that is mostly fixed (and connections sometimes need to be renewed). Mount is the simplest of the two libs and would allow you to the define the connection once and 'require' it wherever you need it.

Comment: While I appreciate your reply, it doesn't really tell me much other than what I already stated in #2 in my list -- I've modified #2 above -- can you edit your answer and justify why mount (which I much prefer to Component) is superior to a simple `def` in my case?

Comment: The fact that connections might need to be renewed (e.g. server crashing)

Comment: The value returned from the `create-conn` function is not, as mentioned above, affected by network connectivity.  This value is simply a specification--a description--of HOW to connect.  So, the server I'm connecting to can go down completely, and if it comes back up, the same value initially returned continues to be usable to connect.  So, there is no way to "renew" a connection, and in fact there is no way to "disconnect," so there is no real state to manage.

Answer (score 1):

Even if `conn` doesn't change after start, you probably want to run the same repository functions against different databases, if you value integration tests. After you load the project in the REPL and start serving request using some database, you may want to write a few integration tests running against a different database. Just an atom is not good enough, if you develop tests and serve requests in parallel. The simplest and I think most idiomatic way is to `def` the connection and pass it as an argument to each repository function (passing another value in the tests). Something with a dynamic variable and an atom can result in less code but turn out more complex.

Comment: This is a tangential remark, but you also see this sort of style in Go codebases (e.g a Server struct with singleton values on it like RedisConnection, DbConnection, Config, etc..., with handlers being functions that take take the same server struct as a param). This sort of dependency injection makes it really easy to test as well.